# What is the use of a package body without package specification in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have faced this question in one interview.

Without specification, Package Body is invalid but they asked advantage. Can you explain what is the use of a package body without package specification in Oracle?

Comment: No advantage. You would had heard something wrong.

Comment: I think the only purpose of this question is to test your confidence in your  understanding of PL/SQL because there are no advantages to PL/SQL Body without a Spec. The correct response would be to challenge the interviewer to come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, package body without its specification is *useless*:

```
SQL> create package body pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test;
  3  end;
  4  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/14     PLS-00201: identifier 'PKG_TEST' must be declared
1/14     PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'PKG_TEST' without its
         specification

SQL> exec pkg_test.p_test;
BEGIN pkg_test.p_test; END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PKG_TEST.P_TEST' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
```

Therefore, I see no advantage(s) in having a package body.

Perhaps it can be used as *code graveyard* - you know, there are some procedures and functions you wrote but you don't need them any more - create a package body and put all that code in there. You won't be able to use them, but will be able to have a look if necessary. Something like your own code repository stored in the database, instead of scattered all over your hard disk in different directories and different kind of files (.SQL, .PRC, .PKG, ...).

Answer (score 1):

I think the premise of the question is misleading and probably wrong.The Interviewer perhaps wanted you to know the difference between variables and procedures that are **not** **defined** in package specification and  defined and called or used internally **within** the package body. A package body can be used to define local procedures and variables without them having defined inside package specification.

```
create or replace package pkg_spec_test
AS
procedure p1;
v_1 NUMBER := 10;
END;
/

create or replace package body pkg_spec_test
AS
procedure p1 AS
 BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('HELLO. I can be called externally');
END p1;

procedure p2 AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('I''m private to package body.');

 END;
 procedure main as
 begin
   p2;  --called within the body;
  END main; 
 END pkg_spec_test;
/


begin
pkg_spec_test.p1;
end;
/
```

Works fine.

```
HELLO. I can be called externally
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

begin
pkg_spec_test.p2;
end;
/
```

Causes error

```
Error starting at line : 30 in command -
begin
pkg_spec_test.p2;
end;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 15:
PLS-00302: component 'P2' must be declared
```

The one below works fine

```
begin
pkg_spec_test.main;
end;
/


I'm private to package body.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Why calling `pkg_spec_test.main;` wont throw error however calling the procedure directly will can. you explain in your question please

Comment: Calling `pkg_spec_test.main;` DOES NOT work. It's the same as calling `p2` and produces the same error.